# Is there a way to deploy a "Stopped" function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm deploying an Azure Function App and we are deploying to EastUS and WestUS. I want to completely stop the app in EastUS. Is there a way to do this within an ARM template?

I am currently stopping just our main triggering function by adding `AzureWebJobs.<TriggerFunction>.Disabled=false` in our ARM template, but that only disables one of our 5 functions in that app. I would like to completely stop the app, or deploy it in a stopped state, and all functions within it for our EastUS deploy.

My other option is to add 4 more rows for each other function in the app but it still leaves the app running, which we do not want.

Thanks

Comment: I've added `az functionapp stop --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup` as a task in the pipeline, but that still only lets me stop the app AFTER it has been deployed

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, you need to use az `functionapp stop --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup` with your task in the pipeline. As a fix, you can move the task above the deployment step in order to stop the function app before you start to deploy.